# Trouble Creating Excel add-in from macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I've created two VBA macro functions that worked fine when used in the current workbook.  I saved as .xla and imported as an add-in.  I then found and activated the add-in through the menus in excel but when I use the functions I get the #NAME error and a description of "The formula contains unrecognized text".  I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you give the part of the code where you have used the formula?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the VBA editor, does your addin show up in the list?  I've had problems before with Excel VBA addins where even though the Addins list says an addin is loaded, it doesn't show up in the VBA editor unless I uncheck it and recheck it in the list.  It's pretty annoying, and I haven't found a way to find the list of Addins I've selected, in order to automatically reload them if necessary...

Hope that helps...